# Angular2 : Bind view with callback variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my angular2 project, I read a csv file with FileReader. After the `onloadend` callback I have a variable which contain the content of my csv file.

Here my component.ts :

```
items: Array<any> = []

...

readCSV (event) {
   let csvFileParseLog = this.csvFileParseLog;
   r.onloadend = function(loadedEvt) {
       devicesFile = files[0];
       let csvFileParseLog = [];
       parseDevicesCsvFile(contents) // One of my function which is an observable
           .subscribe(newItems=> {
               csvFileParseLog.push(newItems); // My result
           },
           exception => { ... }
       );
  };
}
```

I tried to bind`csvFileParseLog` to my view by passing my value into `items` ... whithout success.

Here my componenet.html :

```
<div *ngFor="let c of csvFileParseLog">
    {{ c.value }}
</div>
```

How can I display this content into my view component and loop on it with ngFor ?

Comment: it would be really helpful if you could share the code you've got so far. :)

Comment: Yes of course :) I did it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
r.onloadend = function(loadedEvt) {
```

should be

```
r.onloadend = (loadedEvt) => {
```

otherwise `this` won't work within that function.

and then just use

```
this.csvFileParseLog.push(newItems);
```

and just drop `let csvFileParseLog = this.csvFileParseLog;`

You also might need to inject

```
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

and call it in `subscribe()`

```
       .subscribe(newItems=> {
           this.csvFileParseLog.push(newItems); 
           this.cdRef.detectChanges();
       },
```